# iphone, SBJsonWriter .. converting an object

Tags: xcode, json, object

I want to post a json object to a request. But JSONWriter doesn't seem to convert my object, don't know what I'm doing wrong ...
here's my code for the conversion..

```
    customer = [[Customer alloc] init];

Address *tempAddr = [[Address alloc] init];
tempAddr.Line1=strAddr1 ;
tempAddr.Zip =strPost;
tempAddr.City =strStreet;
[customer setInvoiceAddress:tempAddr];

customer.FirstName=strFirstName;
customer.LastName=strLastName;
customer.CellPhone=strCellPhone;
customer.Phone=strPhone;
customer.Email=strEmail;

SBJsonWriter *writer = [SBJsonWriter alloc];
NSString *jsonConvertedObj = [writer stringWithObject:customer];
NSLog(@"the json converted object ... %@", jsonConvertedObj);
```

Please help. I've no idea what's wrong with the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK SBJSONWriter only supports conversion of dictionaries and arrays to JSON strings. It won't work for arbitrary objects.

---

Edit: Here is the corresponding implementation, which returns nil if the supplied object is neither a dictionary nor an array.

```
- (NSString*)stringWithObject:(id)value {
    if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] || [value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        return [self stringWithFragment:value];
    }

    [self clearErrorTrace];
    [self addErrorWithCode:EFRAGMENT description:@"Not valid type for JSON"];
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so should I use a dictionary object instead of arbitrary or there's another way to get this to work ???

Comment: @donito Yes, I think using a dictionary to store your data would be the easiest way. Alternatively you may read the data you want to convert to JSON from your customer and address objects into an intermediate dictionary and then generate the JSON representation from it. This way you wouldn't need to give up your custom classes.

Comment: thanks but I already converted the code to use a dictionary object. It works fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

To figure out why your Json parsing fails, You shoud use this approach:

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString * jsonTest = [[[SBJsonWriter alloc] init] stringWithObject:jsonTestDictionary error:&error];

    if ( ! jsonTest ) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"%@", jsonTest);
    }
```

Here is a simple code demonstrating how to use it:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "SBJsonWriter.h"
#import "SBJsonParser.h"


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSDictionary* aNestedObject = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                              @"nestedStringValue", @"aStringInNestedObject",
                                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"aNumberInNestedObject",
                                         nil];

        NSArray * aJSonArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"arrayItem1", @"arrayItem2", @"arrayItem3", nil];

        NSDictionary * jsonTestDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                             @"stringValue", @"aString",
                                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"aNumber",
                                             [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.2345f], @"aFloat",
                                             [[NSDate date] description], @"aDate",
                                             aNestedObject, @"nestedObject",
                                             aJSonArray, @"aJSonArray",
                                             nil];

        // create JSON output from dictionary

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSString * jsonTest = [[[SBJsonWriter alloc] init] stringWithObject:jsonTestDictionary error:&error];

        if ( ! jsonTest ) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"%@", jsonTest);
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

outputs

```
{
    "aDate":"2012-09-12 07:39:00 +0000",
    "aFloat":1.2345000505447388,
    "nestedObject":{
        "aStringInNestedObject":"nestedStringValue",
        "aNumberInNestedObject":1
     },
    "aJSonList":["arrayItem1","arrayItem2","arrayItem3"],
    "aString":"stringValue",
    "aNumber":1
}
```

Note:

1. Using 'error' allowed me to figure out that if you write [NSDate
   date] instead of [[NSDate date] description] you will get a "JSON
   serialisation not supported for
   __NSTaggedDate" error.
2. notice the float rounding error... 1.2345 became 1.2345000505447388